# How to separate a string by the comma, but the field doesn't have a fix amount of values in them

Tags: sql, mysql, string, mysql-workbench, delimiter

I am currently using **MySQL Workbench** for this problem
I want to separate a string by the comma, but it does not have a fix amount of values in the field.
Common examples i've seen was someone wanting to separate an address or a full name in a field.

The project i'm working on is on nintendo games. I'm trying to separate these strings which contains the genres of the game. Some games might have 2 genres and another one might have 5 or even 7.

| ID | genre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Role-Playing, Japanese-Style |
| 2 | Action, Fighting, 2D |
| 3 | Strategy, Turn-Based, Tactics |
| 4 | Role-Playing, Strategy, Turn-Based, Japanese-Style, Tactics |

The only solution I can think of is creating a procedure that loops through each field based on the number of delimiters it has. I have a general idea of how it should work, but I just don't know how to write it

There are two expected outputs I would Like
The ideal output would look something like this

| ID | genre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Role-Playing |
| 1 | Japanese-Style |
| 2 | Action, Fighting, 2D |
| 2 | Fighting |
| 2 | 2D |
| 3 | Strategy |
| 3 | Turn-Based |
| 3 | Tactics |

OR

My 2nd ideal output would probably be having the genres separated into a new column.

Comment: always a goo read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows